# Why do I get index out of range error when I have specifically added an if condition to avoid that situation?

Tags: python-3.x, list, debugging

```
def compress(list1):
for i in range(1,len(list1)):
    j=i-1
    k=i+1
    print("\ni is: %d "%i)
    print("j is: %d"%j)
    print("k is: %d"%k)
    print("List is: ")
    print(list1)
    if(list1[i] == list1[j] ):
        print("list1's i element popped")
        list1.pop(i)
        compress(list1)
    if(k != len(list1)):
        if(list[i] == list1[k] ):
            list1.pop(i)
            print("list1's i element popped")
            compress(list1)
    else: 
        pass
return(len(list1))
```

listA=[2,1,2,2]
result = compress(listA)
print(result)

nTestCases =int(input())
for i in range(0,nTestCases):
size=int(input())
Frame=[]
for j in range(0,size):
Frame.append(int(input()))
print(compress(Frame))

Comment: The test should probably be `k < len(list1)`.  Your current `!=` test will catch `k` being one beyond the end of the list, but not two beyond the end (which can happen if you were at the end of the list, and then removed an element from it).